# How to convert Java Image into JPEG array of bytes?

Tags: java, image, encoding, image-manipulation, jpeg

Is there a way to convert a Java Image, encode it into JPEG (but not saving it to a file), and store it as an array of bytes? (byte[]) I need the JPEG-encoded image as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ImageIO`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) has a number of methods for reading and writing images.

For writing to array of bytes, you can write to [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). And then call `toByteArray[]` of the stream object to obtain the byte array.